# How to display page content and a list of posts on the same page?

Tags: templates

I was wondering if there is a way to display the page content and a list of posts from a specific category on the same page in my wordpress blog using a template.

I have a child theme set up, but don't know anything about the wordpress page structure. All of my attempts to achieve this have been unsuccessful so-far.

If someone could help me out that would be great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

php file add the following code snippet

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php
    $post = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'  
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $post ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="text-center">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

it help you to show the all post after the page content

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty broad, so my answer is as well.

Set up a new page template. Create a new page, provide some content and a post thumbnail if you like, and use the new page template. In the template itself, first handle the page data, and then set up a custom query. Loop through the posts and *clean up*. That's basically it.

```
// ...

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

 // ...

<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    // your arguments here
) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    // work with the post as usual, for instance the_title();
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```